# Changing the state of boolean inside a list from a function?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, tkinter

I want to set up a GUI for my command line application, I'm using tkinter for that job. I want to make canvas that acts as a substitute checkbox, with 2 images that should change whenever the user left clicks the canvas.

While working on that problem, I realized a big leap in my knowledge that I would like to tackle. I haven't found a question that relates to my specific problem but if anyone has a link, I would gladly read that first.

What I want to do is use a bind function on the canvas, which connects with a function which checks the state of the Boolean that I provide as a parameter. I have Boolean variable for each canvas.

First I tried to declare the variable inside the initialization of the GUI but I realized that the Boolean gets reset with every loop.

After that I tried to declare them inside of **init**(). Which works if I only use a single variable by simply using that directly in the function.

So my thought was if I take all those variables inside a list, then I can use a for loop on the list and check if the memory location matches to the parameter and if it does it should check the value and then change it.

But apparently at this point I noticed that I have some learning to do. Here is the code:

```
class UploadGUI(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.item_state = True
        self.variation_state = True
        self.active_state = True
        self.barcode_state = True
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        ...
        if(isfile('.../checkbox-unchecked.png')):
            self.uncheckedimg = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='.../checkbox-unchecked.png')
        ...
        self.itemup_check = tkinter.Canvas(width=150,height=40,bg=self.bg
                                       , bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.itemup_check.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, item = self.itemup_check, check = self.item_state, image1 = self.uncheckedimg, image2 = self.checkedimg : self.switchImage(item, check, image1, image2))

        self.itemup_check.create_image(0,0,image=self.uncheckedimg,anchor="nw")
        self.itemup_check.grid(column=0, row=4,sticky="EW")
        ...


    def switchImage(self, element, check, image1, image2):
        print(id(check))
        for state in [self.item_state]:
            print(id(state))
            if(id(check) == id(state)):
                if(state):
                    element.create_image(0,0,image=image1,anchor="nw")
                else:
                    element.create_image(0,0,image=image2,anchor="nw")
                state = not state
                print(id(state))
```

I realized that the memory location changes in between the 2 prints of state and I feel like it is crucial that I understand what is happening there.

Console Output:

10744128

10744096

For testing purposes I only included one of the state variables into the for loop, usually there would be four.

Comment: Booleans are immutable in Python: it sounds like you're used to a much lower-level programming language. You cannot pass a reference to a boolean and change the state of boolean, assigning will merely re-assign the variable to a new object. You have to modify it in the list, which means you must pass the list itself.

Comment: If you're iterating over the list, you may do something like: `for i, s in enumerate(self.state)` to iterate over an index, boolean pair, and then if you want to modify it, can do `self.state[i] = not s`.